# Randomly Rotate PHP files in sidebar on page refresh

Tags: php, jquery

I have 4 php files which all have a small PHP and jQuery game inside.

The files are as follows:

```
/game1.php
/game2.php
/game3.php
/game4.php
```

Every time the page is refreshed I want one of the games to show in the sidebar. When the page is refreshed again, a different game and so.

Is there a way to include files in the sidebar at random via some kind of query on page refresh, if so, could someone please help me with the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$games = array('game1.php','game2.php','game3.php','game4.php');
session_start();
$used = array();
if (isset($_SESSION['used'])){
    $used = $_SESSION['used'];
}
$usable = array_diff($games,$used);
if (sizeof($usable)==0){
    $usable = $games;
    $_SESSION['used'] = array();
}

$inUse = $usable[array_rand($usable)];
$_SESSION['used'][] = $inUse;

include($inUse);
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered, but the question has to be awarded to Wicked, works seamlessly. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
include '/game' . rand(1, 4) . '.php';
```

Comment: This will lead to dublicate games

Comment: @ChrisVisser if author asked for random, random is known for... being unknown, so, I think it makes sense to think it can repeat values.

Comment: He clearly stated: A different game when the page loads. This means it cannot be the same as the previous value.

Comment: He has stated that he wishes a random order, not duplicates

Answer (score 1):

```
$FileNames = array ('File1.php','File2.php','File3.php','File4.php'); // Can later be autodetected if file structure gets too big      
$FileNames = array_rand($FileNames); 
foreach ($FileNames AS $Links){ 
     echo $Links; 
    }
```

If you wish to make these clickable:

```
foreach ($FileNames AS $Links){ 
     echo "<a href=".$Links.">".$Links."</a>"; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$file_array= array('game1.php','game2.php','game3.php','game4.php');
$rand = rand (0, count ($file_array)); 
include ($file_array[$rand]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find your answer in sessions since you don't want the last viewed game to show up on a next page refresh:

```
//Fill in array
$games = array('game1' => 'PONG', 'game2' => 'Donkey Kong', 'game3' => 'Patience', 'game4' => 'LoL');
//Delete the current game from the array
unset($games[$_SESSION['currentGame']]);
//Shuffle the array and pick the last one 
$game = end(shuffle($games));
include($game.'.php');
//Update session for next page refresh
$_SESSION['currentGame'] = $game;
```